# Convergence of Random Variable (Measure Theory)

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If $W_n$ has a Poisson(n) distribution, how to show $X_n=(W_n-n)/\sqrt{n}$ goes to N(0, 1) by using some measure theories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure about the measure theoretical approach. Usually this problem can be tackled by considering the mgf/characteristic function:

$$\begin{align}
M_{X_n}(t) & = E\left[\exp\left\{t\frac {W_n - n} {\sqrt{n}}\right\}\right] \\
& = e^{-t\sqrt{n}}E\left[\exp\left\{\frac {t} {\sqrt{n}} W_n\right\}\right] \\
& = e^{-t\sqrt{n}}
\exp\left\{n\left(\exp\left\{\frac {t} {\sqrt{n}}\right\} - 1\right)\right\} \\
& = \exp\left\{n\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {1} {k!}\left(\frac {t} {\sqrt{n}}\right)^k - 1\right) - t\sqrt{n}\right\} \\
& =  \exp\left\{t\sqrt{n} + \frac {t^2} {2} + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac {1} {k!}\frac {t^k} {n^{\frac {k} {2} - 1}}  - t\sqrt{n}\right\} \\
& =  \exp\left\{\frac {t^2} {2} + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac {1} {k!}\frac {t^k} {n^{\frac {k} {2} - 1}}\right\} \\
& \to \exp\left\{\frac {t^2} {2}\right\} \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align} $$
So the mgf of $X_n$ converges to the mgf of $N(0, 1)$, and thus $X_n$ converge to $N(0, 1)$ in distribution.